# What does this path in circle CI config.yml refer to?

Tags: cypress, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am new to cypress and CircleCI. The person working in my company who left had done the setup for CircleCI. I want to know what this path refers to:

`/root/repo/cypress/screenshots`. ??

It seems like the screenshots and videos taken when cypress test fails when run through CircleCI are located here.

What is `/root/repo` ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. The screenshots and the videos that CircleCI saved when cypress tests are run are located under Artifacts under Jobs. I found them in the old experience CircleCI.